# Errors in aws.alexa url_info function

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to use the aws.alexa package to retrieve traffic info about a list of urls, but whenever I try to use the url_info() function, this error pops up:

```
    url_info("http://www.google.com")
    >Request ID:  1e7cdXXXXXXXXXXXa8-c0700a4eXXXX 
    >Response Status:  Success 
    >Error in urlinfo_payload[[2]][[1]][[2]] : subscript out of bounds
```

Anyone has got any idea why it is behaving like that?

Whenever I try this other function the error is different:

```
    traffic <- traffic_history("http://www.google.com")
    >Error in as.Date.default(date, "%Y%m%d") : 
    >do not know how to convert 'date' to class “Date”
```

Other functions like browse_categories work, so I guess the problem does not rely with authentication:

```
    browse_categories(path="Top/Arts")
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am the package maintainer. Thomas Leeper pointed me to this.

First, apologies. the traffic_history was a bug. It should have been caught in the tests but somehow unit tests weren't running. Latest dev release solves it. And it should be on CRAN super soon:

```
devtools::install_github("cloudyr/aws.alexa")
library(aws.alexa)
set_secret_key("XXXXX", "XXXXX")
traffic <- traffic_history("http://www.google.com")
head(traffic)
```

`date page_views_per_million page_views_per_user rank reach_per_million
1  2017-03-29                  87520                8.68    1            439900
2  2017-03-30                  87640                8.54    1            443300
3  2017-03-31                  83900                8.23    1            431900`

I couldn't replicate the issue for url_info. Can you try again and reach out if it is still giving an error.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for the late answer, for now i'll post the script with which I managed to obtain informations through taking just part of the url_info function. I know this will not be clear. The error is still there if I use just the function.

```
library(rvest)
library(aws.alexa)
library(aws.signature)
library(httr)
library(XML)
require(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

#first run: setSecretKey, trafficHistory, alexa_GET

url <- read_html("http://www.lombardiapress.it/lombardiapress/portale/index.php?s=3#")

newsP <- url %>%
    html_nodes(xpath='//*[(@id = "divBergamo") or (@id = "divBrescia") or (@id = "divComo") or (@id = "divCremona") or (@id = "divLecco")
               or (@id = "divLodi") or (@id = "divMantova") or (@id = "divMilano") or (@id = "divMonza") or (@id = "divPavia") or (@id = "divSondrio")
               or (@id = "divVarese")]//a') 

df <- bind_rows(lapply(xml_attrs(newsP), function(x) data.frame(as.list(x), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)))
head(df)
df <- df[!duplicated(df$href),]
df <- df[!is.na(df$href),]


set_secret_key(key="XXXXXXXXXXXZP4FQ", secret="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX+dlpdqip")

avg <- data.frame(pageviewsPerMillion = numeric(), pageViewsPerUser = numeric(), Rank = numeric(),
                      reachPerMillion =numeric(), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)


for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  query <-  list(Action = "TrafficHistory", Url = df[i,2], ResponseGroup="History", range=15, start="20170201")
  traffic_payload <- alexa_GET(query)
  res_list <- lapply(lapply(traffic_payload[[2]][[1]], "[[", 4)[[1]], unlist) #Had to change the indexing here cause it wasn't pointing to the right node (I think this was the issue)
  db <- rbind.fill(lapply(res_list,function(y){as.data.frame(t(y),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)}))
  db <- db[,-1]
  #db <- as.data.frame(t(data.frame(res_list,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)))
  db <- lapply(db, as.numeric)
  url[i] <- df[i,2]
  avg[i,] <- data.frame(pageviewsPerMillion = mean(db$PageViews.PerMillion, na.rm = TRUE), pageViewsPerUser = mean(db$PageViews.PerUser, na.rm = TRUE), Rank = mean(db$Rank, na.rm = TRUE),
                        reachPerMillion = mean(db$Reach.PerMillion, na.rm = TRUE))
}
avg$url <- unlist(url)

avg <- avg[!is.na(avg$pageviewsPerMillion),]
setwd("~/R projects/Alexa rank")
write.csv2(avg, "Ranking_Testate_Lombardia.csv")

ggplot() + geom_col(data=avg, aes(reorder(url, pageviewsPerMillion), pageviewsPerMillion)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1, size = 20), legend.position = "none")

ggplot() + geom_col(data=avg, aes(reorder(url, pageViewsPerUser), pageViewsPerUser)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1, size = 20), legend.position = "none")

ggplot() + geom_col(data=avg, aes(reorder(url, 1/Rank), 1/Rank)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1, size = 20), legend.position = "none")

ggplot() + geom_col(data=avg, aes(reorder(url, reachPerMillion), reachPerMillion)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1, size = 20), legend.position = "none")
```